# Tcp and udp max packet size

Tags: c, linux, tcp, udp, packet-sniffers

When using `recvfrom(2)` to get packet from network I get each time 1 packet.

What is the max length of TCP/UDP packet that get with this function?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't process packets.

Comment: @Barmar When I use `recvfrom` I get each time 1 pakcet(like I can see in wireshark)

Comment: [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) have a 16-bit total-size field, which means it can transfer up to 65535 bytes in a single packet (header *and* sub-protol headers included).

Comment: @paramikoooo That's not a requirement, it may just be due to an optimization.

Answer (score 4):

There's no fixed limit in TCP, because it's a stream protocol, not a datagram protocol.

In UDP over IPv4, the limit is 65,507 bytes. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol):

> **Length**
> This field specifies the length in bytes of the UDP header and UDP data. The minimum length is 8 bytes, the length of the header. The field size sets a theoretical limit of 65,535 bytes (8 byte header + 65,527 bytes of data) for a UDP datagram. However the actual limit for the data length, which is imposed by the underlying IPv4 protocol, is 65,507 bytes (65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP header).

> Using IPv6 [jumbograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbogram) it is possible to have UDP datagrams of size greater than 65,535 bytes. [RFC 2675](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2675) specifies that the length field is set to zero if the length of the UDP header plus UDP data is greater than 65,535.

Note that using extremely large UDP datagrams can be problematic. Few network links have such large MTUs, so the datagram will likely be fragmented. If any fragment is lost, the entire datagram will have to be resent by the application layer (if the application requires and implements reliability). TCP normally used Path MTU Discovery to send the stream in segments that fit in the minimum MTU of all the links in the path; if a segment is lost, TCP can just retransmit the segments after that (or just the lost segment if Selective Acknowledgement is implemented, which most TCP implementations now offer).

Comment: Thanks, I've added clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`recvfrom` will always return exactly one packet for UDP.  UDP packets can be up to 64KB in size give or take for a few header bytes.  In practice, most UDP protocols don't ever send that much data in a single packet. So your buffer size passed to `recvfrom` can be much less depending on what your protocol dictates.

For TCP, you typically use `recv`, not `recvfrom` to read incoming data from a connected socket.  Many will point out, TCP is a stream protocol, not a message/packet protocol like UDP. As such `recv` will give you back a non-deterministic amount of bytes between 1 and the size of the buffer being passed in to the `recv` call itself.  Always check the return value from a `recv` call - it's not guaranteed to give you any particular byte count.

Comment: can I use `recv` for TCP and UDP ?

Comment: Re "*For TCP, you typically use `recv`, not `recvfrom`*", True, but only because it's shorter to say `recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags)` than the equivalent `recvfrom(sockfd, buf, len, flags, NULL, NULL)`

Comment: @paramikoooo, Re "*can I use recv for TCP and UDP?*", Yes. For UDP, that will allow anyone to send datagrams to the socket. For TCP, using `recv` or `read` is par for course.

Comment: IIRC anyone can send datagrams to a UDP socket regardless of which function you use. But with recv, you don't know who sent them.